# NextJS14 Custom metatags

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I need to add metatags with class name (for Elastic)
Example is

```
<meta class="elastic" name="{FIELD_NAME_1}" content="{FIELD_VALUE_1}">
```

By default they are adding without any class and there is no way to add it.

I didnt find anything how to do it in Next documentation so could someone tells me what the correct way to do that?

UPD: its server component and it should be server component, i cant change it to client